# ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA does not fire for 60 seconds?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to connect my Flash game to a TCP server, which is hosted on my own machine (for development purposes).  I've successfully created a TCP stream in PHP:

```
<?php
$port=<some number>;
$server=<some local vhost>;
$socket=@stream_socket_server("tcp://$server:$port", $errno, $errstr);
$conn = stream_socket_accept($socket);
while($conn){
  $foo=fgets($conn);
  fwrite($conn, $foo);
}
```

And here is the Actionscript code I wrote:

```
// import statements not included
public var socket:Socket=new Socket;
public var server:String="HIDDEN";
public var port:uint=HIDDEN;
public function connectSocket():void
{
  socket.connect(server,port);
  socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA,onSocketData);
  socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT,onSocketConnect);
}
public function onSocketConnect(event:Event):void
{
  trace("CONNECT at "+new Date().toUTCString());
  socket.writeUTF("Foo");socket.flush();
}
public function onSocketData(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
  trace("PROGRESSEVENT at "+new Date().toUTCString());
  trace("RESPONSE FROM SEVER: "+socket.readUTF()+" at "+new Date().toUTCString());
}
```

However, in running this I get:

```
[trace] CONNECT at Wed Jul 30 14:54:27 2014 UTC
[trace] PROGRESSEVENT at Wed Jul 30 14:55:27 2014 UTC
[trace] RESPONSE FROM SEVER: Foo at Wed Jul 30 14:55:27 2014 UTC
```

It is usually exactly 60 seconds, however once or twice it was a little more.  The server is hosted on my own machine, it should not take 60 seconds to connect to my own machine, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A message needs to end with a newline (\n) in order to be flushed properly.  So the line in the code should go:

```
socket.writeUTF("Foo\n");
```

Instead of:

```
socket.writeUTF("Foo");
```